# Sampling keys due to their values

Tags: python, dictionary, sampling

I have a dictionary in python with key->value as `str->int`. If I have to chose a key based on it's own value, then as the value gets larger the key has a lower possibility of being chosen.

For example, if `key1=2` and `key2->1`, then the attitude of `key1` should be `2:1`.

How can I do this?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056151/random-python-dictionary-key-weighted-by-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Construct a CDF-like list like this:

```
def build_cdf(distrib):
    cdf = []
    val = 0
    for key, freq in distrib.items():
        val += freq
        cdf.append((val, key))
    return (val, cdf)
```

This function returns a tuple, the 1st value is the sum of probabilities, and 2nd value is the CDF.

**2.** Construct the sampler like this:

```
import random
def sample_from_cdf(val_and_cdf):
    (val, cdf) = val_and_cdf;
    rand = random.uniform(0, val)
    # use bisect.bisect_left to reduce search time from O(n) to O(log n).
    return [key for index, key in cdf if index > rand][0]
```

Usage:

```
x = build_cdf({"a":0.2, "b":0.3, "c":0.5});
y = [sample_from_cdf(x) for i in range(0,100000)];
print (len([t for t in y if t == "a"]))   # 19864
print (len([t for t in y if t == "b"]))   # 29760
print (len([t for t in y if t == "c"]))   # 50376
```

You may want to make this into a class.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are too large for gnibler's approach:

Build a list of tuples `(key, index)`, where `index` is the sum of all values that come before key in the list (this would be the index of the first occurrence of `key` gnibler's list `c`. Also calculate the sum of all values (`n`).

Now, generate a random number `x`between 0 and `n - 1`. Find the last entry in the list with `index < x`. Since the list is sorted by index, you can use binary search to do that efficiently.

**Update:** KennyTM's code is an implementation of this, except that he uses a brute-force linear search instead of binary search; this will be inefficient if the number of keys are large.

Comment: +1. This is known as Roulette Wheel Selection or Fitness Proportional Selection, and is commonly used in genetic algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It the values are not too large, you can do it this way

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> d={"key1":2,"key2":1}
>>> c=[]
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...  c+=[k]*v
... 
>>> choice(c)
'key1'
>>> sum(1 for x in range(100) if choice(c)=="key1")
63
>>> sum(1 for x in range(100) if choice(c)=="key2")
36
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple version of the algorithm from oefe's and KennyTM's answers:

```
def select_weighted(d):
   offset = random.randint(0, sum(d.itervalues())-1)
   for k, v in d.iteritems():
      if offset < v:
         return k
      offset -= v
```