# Fast random weighted selection across all rows of a stochastic matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, random

`numpy.random.choice` allows for weighted selection from a vector, i.e.

```py
arr = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
weights = numpy.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.3])
choice = numpy.random.choice(arr, p=weights)
```

selects 1 with probability 0.2, 2 with probability 0.5, and 3 with probability 0.3.

What if we wanted to do this quickly in a vectorized fashion for a 2D array (matrix) for which each of the rows are a vector of probabilities? That is, we want a vector of choices from a stochastic matrix? This is the super slow way:

```py
import numpy as np

m = 10
n = 100 # Or some very large number

items = np.arange(m)
prob_weights = np.random.rand(m, n)
prob_matrix = prob_weights / prob_weights.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)

choices = np.zeros((n,))
# This is slow, because of the loop in Python
for i in range(n):
    choices[i] = np.random.choice(items, p=prob_matrix[:,i])
```

`print(choices)`:

```
array([ 4.,  7.,  8.,  1.,  0.,  4.,  3.,  7.,  1.,  5.,  7.,  5.,  3.,
        1.,  9.,  1.,  1.,  5.,  9.,  8.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  6.,  4.,  3.,
        8.,  4.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  0.,  1.,  8.,  5.,  3.,  9.,  9.,  6.,
        5.,  4.,  8.,  4.,  2.,  4.,  0.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  5.,  9.,  3.,
        9.,  9.,  7.,  9.,  3.,  9.,  4.,  8.,  8.,  7.,  6.,  4.,  6.,
        7.,  9.,  5.,  0.,  6.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  4.,  7.,  0.,  6.,
        3.,  5.,  8.,  0.,  8.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  9.,
        9.,  4.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  8.,  0.,  6.,  1.])
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24140114/586086) suggests that `cumsum` and `bisect` could be a potential approach, and is fast. But while `numpy.cumsum(arr, axis=1)` can do this along one axis of a numpy array, the [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) function only works on a single array at a time. Similarly, [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) only works on 1D arrays as well.

Is there a quick way to do this using only vectorized operations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a fully vectorized version that's pretty fast:

```
def vectorized(prob_matrix, items):
    s = prob_matrix.cumsum(axis=0)
    r = np.random.rand(prob_matrix.shape[1])
    k = (s < r).sum(axis=0)
    return items[k]
```

*In theory*, `searchsorted` is the right function to use for looking up the random value in the cumulatively summed probabilities, but with `m` being relatively small, `k = (s < r).sum(axis=0)` ends up being much faster.  Its time complexity is O(m), while the `searchsorted` method is O(log(m)), but that will only matter for much larger `m`.  *Also*, `cumsum` is O(m), so both `vectorized` and @perimosocordiae's `improved` are O(m).  (If your `m` is, in fact, much larger, you'll have to run some tests to see how large `m` can be before this method is slower.)

Here's the timing I get with `m = 10` and `n = 10000` (using the functions `original` and `improved` from @perimosocordiae's answer):

```
In [115]: %timeit original(prob_matrix, items)
1 loops, best of 3: 270 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit improved(prob_matrix, items)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.9 ms per loop

In [117]: %timeit vectorized(prob_matrix, items)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1 ms per loop
```

The full script where the functions are defined is:

```
import numpy as np


def improved(prob_matrix, items):
    # transpose here for better data locality later
    cdf = np.cumsum(prob_matrix.T, axis=1)
    # random numbers are expensive, so we'll get all of them at once
    ridx = np.random.random(size=n)
    # the one loop we can't avoid, made as simple as possible
    idx = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
    for i, r in enumerate(ridx):
        idx[i] = np.searchsorted(cdf[i], r)
    # fancy indexing all at once is faster than indexing in a loop
    return items[idx]


def original(prob_matrix, items):
    choices = np.zeros((n,))
    # This is slow, because of the loop in Python
    for i in range(n):
        choices[i] = np.random.choice(items, p=prob_matrix[:,i])
    return choices


def vectorized(prob_matrix, items):
    s = prob_matrix.cumsum(axis=0)
    r = np.random.rand(prob_matrix.shape[1])
    k = (s < r).sum(axis=0)
    return items[k]


m = 10
n = 10000 # Or some very large number

items = np.arange(m)
prob_weights = np.random.rand(m, n)
prob_matrix = prob_weights / prob_weights.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Great answer! Regarding your initial comment, I don't think you can even do a vectorized `searchsorted` on a 2D array, can you? So it's going to be slow anyway.

Comment: I mean `searchsorted` used in a loop, as in the `improved` function.  For sufficiently large `m`, the better time complexity of the code in `improved` (even with its slow python loop) will beat the `vectorized` solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to completely vectorize this, but you can still get a decent speedup by vectorizing as much as you can. Here's what I came up with:

```
def improved(prob_matrix, items):
    # transpose here for better data locality later
    cdf = np.cumsum(prob_matrix.T, axis=1)
    # random numbers are expensive, so we'll get all of them at once
    ridx = np.random.random(size=n)
    # the one loop we can't avoid, made as simple as possible
    idx = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
    for i, r in enumerate(ridx):
      idx[i] = np.searchsorted(cdf[i], r)
    # fancy indexing all at once is faster than indexing in a loop
    return items[idx]
```

Testing against the version in the question:

```
def original(prob_matrix, items):
    choices = np.zeros((n,))
    # This is slow, because of the loop in Python
    for i in range(n):
        choices[i] = np.random.choice(items, p=prob_matrix[:,i])
    return choices
```

Here's the speedup (using the setup code given in the question):

```
In [45]: %timeit original(prob_matrix, items)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop

In [46]: %timeit improved(prob_matrix, items)
The slowest run took 4.15 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 157 µs per loop
```

I'm not sure why there's a big discrepancy in timings for my version, but even the slowest run (~650 µs) is still almost 5x faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think part of the reason is the inherent slowness of `numpy.random.choice` in the post I linked. But I think having a for loop in Python is still not going to be great when n=10000, for example. There has to be a better way!