# Vectorizing numpy.random.multinomial

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, random

I am trying to vectorize the following code:

```
for i in xrange(s.shape[0]):
            a[i] = np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1,s[i,:]))
```

`s.shape = 400 x 100` [given].

`a.shape = 400` [expected].

s is a 2D matrix, which contains the probabilities of  pairs. 
The multinomial is expected to draw a random sample from each row of the s matrix and store the result in vector a.

Comment: Are all the rows of `s` guaranteed to have a sum of `1`?

Comment: Here's an attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187130/fast-random-weighted-selection-across-all-rows-of-a-stochastic-matrix/34190035

Answer (score 3):

In the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952419/vectorizing-numpy-random-multinomial#comment61463935_36952419), it is said that there is an attempt at vectorizing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190035/2504700), however, it's not *only* an attempt. It is a complete solution the this question too.

The goal of the question is to obtain the *index* of the postion containing the 1 of the multinomial event. That is, the following realization `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]` will yield 14. Thus, it is actually equivalent to executing:

```
np.random.choice(np.arange(len(p)),p=p) # here, p is s[i,:]
```

Therefore, [Warren Weckesser solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190035/2504700) to *Fast random weighted selection across all rows of a stochastic matrix* is also a solution to this question. The only difference is whether the vectors of probability are defined in rows or in columns, which can be solved easily either transposing `s` to be used as `prob_matrix` or defining a custom version of `vectorized` that works for `s` strtucture:

```
def vectorized(prob_matrix, items):
    s = prob_matrix.cumsum(axis=1)
    r = np.random.rand(prob_matrix.shape[0])
    k = (s < r).sum(axis=1)
    return items[k]
```

In this question, with dimensions 400x400, the speedup is around a factor 10:

```
%%timeit
a = np.empty(400)
for i in range(s.shape[0]):
    a[i] = np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1,s[i,:]))
# 5.96 ms ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit 
vals = np.arange(400,dtype=int)
vectorized(s,vals)
# 544 µs ± 5.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: There's a small typo with `np.random_choice` which should be `np.random.choice`. 

I wasn't able to edit as it is just a 1 character difference.

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
[np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1,s[i,:])) for i in xrange(s.shape[0])]
```