# Vectorizing `numpy.random.choice` for given 2D array of probabilities along an axis

Tags: python, numpy, random, vectorization

Numpy has the `random.choice` function, which allows you to sample from a categorical distribution. How would you repeat this over an axis? To illustrate what I mean, here is my current code:

```
categorical_distributions = np.array([
    [.1, .3, .6],
    [.2, .4, .4],
])
_, n = categorical_distributions.shape
np.array([np.random.choice(n, p=row)
          for row in categorical_distributions])
```

Ideally, I would like to eliminate the for loop.

Comment: Looks like a job for [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: @Galen The performance numbers would be comparable to the posted loopy solution, if not worse.

Comment: @Divakar Agreed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187130/fast-random-weighted-selection-across-all-rows-of-a-stochastic-matrix

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one vectorized way to get the random indices per row, with `a` as the `2D` array of probabilities -

```
(a.cumsum(1) > np.random.rand(a.shape[0])[:,None]).argmax(1)
```

Generalizing to cover both along the rows and columns for `2D` array -

```
def random_choice_prob_index(a, axis=1):
    r = np.expand_dims(np.random.rand(a.shape[1-axis]), axis=axis)
    return (a.cumsum(axis=axis) > r).argmax(axis=axis)
```

Let's verify with the given sample by running it over a million times -

```
In [589]: a = np.array([
     ...:     [.1, .3, .6],
     ...:     [.2, .4, .4],
     ...: ])

In [590]: choices = [random_choice_prob_index(a)[0] for i in range(1000000)]

# This should be close to first row of given sample
In [591]: np.bincount(choices)/float(len(choices))
Out[591]: array([ 0.099781,  0.299436,  0.600783])
```

**Runtime test**

Original loopy way -

```
def loopy_app(categorical_distributions):
    m, n = categorical_distributions.shape
    out = np.empty(m, dtype=int)
    for i,row in enumerate(categorical_distributions):
        out[i] = np.random.choice(n, p=row)
    return out
```

Timings on bigger array -

```
In [593]: a = np.array([
     ...:     [.1, .3, .6],
     ...:     [.2, .4, .4],
     ...: ])

In [594]: a_big = np.repeat(a,100000,axis=0)

In [595]: %timeit loopy_app(a_big)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.54 s per loop

In [596]: %timeit random_choice_prob_index(a_big)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: Excellent answer. How would you implement choice without replacement?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In case it's relevant for anyone, this method is based on the idea of inverse transform sampling, see e.g. https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/inverse_transform_sampling.html