# How to add masking noise to numpy 2-D matrix in a vectorized manner?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy 2-D array `X` with shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. I want to apply masking noise to each sample i.e. each row. Basically, for each row entry, I want to randomly select a fraction `frac` of the total `n_features` elements and set them to `0`.

I have vectorized the inner part of the loop till now, but cannot get rid of the outer `i` loop.

My current code is given below.

```
def add_noise(X, frac):
    X_noise = X.copy()

    n_samples = X.shape[0]
    n_features = X.shape[1]

    for i in range(n_samples):
        mask = np.random.randint(0, n_features, int(frac * n_features))
        X_noise[i][mask] = 0

    return X_noise
```

An example is shown below.

```
test_arr = np.arange(1, 11)
test_arr = np.array([test_arr, test_arr])
print(test_arr)
print(add_noise(test_arr, 0.3))

[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]]
[[ 1  0  3  4  5  6  0  8  9  0]   # 0.3 * num_features = 3 random elements
 [ 0  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  0 10]]  # for each row set to 0
```

How do I get rid of the outer loop?

Comment: Do you need control over the `n_features` dimension?

Comment: @norok2 Can you kindly elaborate? If you mean the no. of elements being set to 0, then yes.

Comment: No, I mean if you need different `frac` values for each `n_features`

Comment: @norok2 No, the `frac` value is same for all the samples.

Comment: Also, do you require `frac` to be exact, or is it good if this is "on average"? Meaning, in your example, that exactly 3 items must be set to 0 (per row).

Comment: @norok2 Yes. For the given example, exactly 3 items must be set to 0 per row.

Comment: OK. Then watch out that your code could also fail if some of the indexes get repeated in `randint()`. You probably want to use `np.random.choice()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from using [`np.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) to generate the full matrix of indices, one element per row:

```
k = int(frac * n_features)
indices = np.random.randint(0, n_features, size=(n_samples, k))
X_noise[np.arange(n_samples)[:, None], indices] = 0
```

The index `np.arange(n_samples)[:, None]` makes the range broadcast to shape `n_samples, k`. This approach has the advantage of not requiring an intermediate step with a mask.

There are a couple of potential problems with this approach:

1. `k = int(frac * n_features)` is not necessarily the closest integer to the actual fraction you are looking for. Something more like `k = math.round(frac * n_features)`.
2. `np.random.randint` samples with replacement. That means that you will get collisions on the same row in the index occasionally. If you are OK with that, that's fine. If not, you can sample without replacement using [`np.random.choice(n_features, replace=False)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). The problem is that you would then have to loop over each row individually.

A more "honest" approach, in my opinion, would be to generate a sequence of random numbers, and simply threshold them at `frac`, so that your *overall* noise approached `frac`, but the noise in each row would be random. The numbers could be generated with something like [`np.random.sample`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.sample.html):

```
X_noise[np.random.sample(size=X_noise.shape) < frac] = 0
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use `np.random.choice(...)` to generate a `num_samples x k` array sampling from `[0, num_features)`? Then the approach would remain almost the same.

Comment: @pmcarpan. At that point, you yould have to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/47722005/2988730

Answer (score 1):

try creating a map of zeroes and ones, and multiply the test array with the map:

```
zero_map = np.round(np.random.rand(*test_arr.shape) * (1-frac))
test_arr = test_arr * zero_map
```

Comment: Or just use the mask as-is: `test_arr[~mask] = 0`

Comment: something like `np.round(np.random.rand(*test_arr.shape) < (1-frac))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the numpy function apply_along_axis.

```
def add_noise(X, frac):
    X_noise = X.copy()

    n_samples = X.shape[0]
    n_features = X.shape[1]

    mask = np.concatenate((np.ones((n_samples,int(frac * n_features)), dtype=np.bool),
                           np.zeros((n_samples, n_features - int(frac * n_features)), dtype=np.bool)),
                           axis=1)
    np.apply_along_axis(np.random.shuffle,1,mask)
    X_noise[mask] = 0
    return X_noise
```