# How to improve np.random.choice() looping efficiency

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to apply `np.random.choice` to a big array with different weights, and wondering any way could avoid looping and improve the performance? Over here `len(weights)` could be millions.

```
weights = [[0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
           [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
           ...
           [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]]

choice = [1, 2, 3]
ret = np.zeros((len(weights), 20))
for i in range(len(weights)):
    ret[i] = np.random.choice(choice, 20, p=weights[i])
```

Comment: I am afraid that you can't help but looping. Perhaps, you could still speed things up by using `numba`? One thing that could help is, if you have a lot of `weights` duplicates, you could generate those with a single `np.random.choice()` call and put it in the right `ret` place afterwards. Also, you may want to change: `for i in range(len(weights)): ...` into `for i, weight in enumerate(weights): ...` (but that's not going to buy you speed, it is just stylistic good practice).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser How would they incorporate number of items in the linked one?

Comment: @Divakar, well, you know, broadcasting, etc. :)  OK, it isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: That is the shape of 'weights'? It may be useful for benchmarking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a generalization of my answer in [Fast random weighted selection across all rows of a stochastic matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187130/fast-random-weighted-selection-across-all-rows-of-a-stochastic-matrix):

```
def vectorized_choice(p, n, items=None):
    s = p.cumsum(axis=1)
    r = np.random.rand(p.shape[0], n, 1)
    q = np.expand_dims(s, 1) >= r
    k = q.argmax(axis=-1)
    if items is not None:
        k = np.asarray(items)[k]
    return k
```

`p` is expected to be a two-dimensional array whose rows are probability vectors. `n` is the number of samples to draw from the distribution defined by each row. If `items` is None, the samples are integers in `range(0, p.shape[1])`.  If `items` is not None, it is expected to be a sequence with length `p.shape[1]`.

Example:

```
In [258]: p = np.array([[0.1, 0.5, 0.4], [0.75, 0, 0.25], [0, 0, 1], [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]])                                                   

In [259]: p                                                                                                                              
Out[259]: 
array([[0.1       , 0.5       , 0.4       ],
       [0.75      , 0.        , 0.25      ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]])

In [260]: vectorized_choice(p, 20)                                                                                                       
Out[260]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2]])

In [261]: vectorized_choice(p, 20, items=[1, 2, 3])                                                                                      
Out[261]: 
array([[2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Timing for `p` with shape `(1000000, 3)`:

```
In [317]: p = np.random.rand(1000000, 3)

In [318]: p /= p.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

In [319]: %timeit vectorized_choice(p, 20, items=np.arange(1, p.shape[1]+1))
1.89 s ± 28.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Here's the timing for Divakar's function:

```
In [320]: %timeit random_choice_prob_vectorized(p, 20, choice=np.arange(1, p.shape[1]+1))
7.33 s ± 43.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The difference will be less pronounced if you increase the number of columns in `p`, and if you make the number of columns big enough,  Divakar's function will be faster. E.g.

```
In [321]: p = np.random.rand(1000, 120)

In [322]: p /= p.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

In [323]: %timeit vectorized_choice(p, 20, items=np.arange(1, p.shape[1]+1))
6.41 ms ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [324]: %timeit random_choice_prob_vectorized(p, 20, choice=np.arange(1, p.shape[1]+1))
6.29 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Good to see the timings! Does make sense.

Comment: Updated my solution. Not as good as yours, but much better than my previous one. Could you take the trouble of updating the timings? Thanks!

Comment: @Divakar, OK, but in my tests, the new version is actually a bit slower than the older version. :(

Comment: Thanks, but in vectorized_choice, prob_matrix should be p, right?

Comment: @Nick, yes, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing idea from [Vectorizing `numpy.random.choice` for given 2D array of probabilities along an axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722393/) alongwith [idea from vectorized `searchsorted`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862/), here's one vectorized way -

```
def random_choice_prob_vectorized(weights, num_items, choice=None):
    weights = np.asarray(weights)

    w = weights.cumsum(1)
    r = np.random.rand(len(weights),num_items)

    m,n = w.shape
    o = np.arange(m)[:,None]
    w_o = (w+o).ravel()
    r_o = (r+o).ravel()
    idx = np.searchsorted(w_o,r_o).reshape(m,-1)%n
    if choice is not None:
        return np.asarray(choice)[idx]
    else:
        return idx
```

Sample run to verify using [`2D bincount`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/) -

```
In [28]: weights = [[0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
    ...:            [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
    ...:            [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]]
    ...: 
    ...: choice = [1, 2, 3]
    ...: num_items = 20000

In [29]: out = random_choice_prob_vectorized(weights, num_items, choice)

# Use 2D bincount to get per average occurences and verify against weights
In [75]: bincount2D_vectorized(out)/num_items
Out[75]: 
array([[0.     , 0.09715, 0.4988 , 0.40405],
       [0.     , 0.1983 , 0.40235, 0.39935],
       [0.     , 0.30025, 0.29485, 0.4049 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like each row of the resulting array is independent of other rows. I am not sure how bad is the performance now. If it really is a concern, I would try to use python's `multiprocessing` module to run random number generations with several processes in parallel. It should help.