# Sampling a random integer 'N' times according to predetermined probabilities, where the probability is different each time

Tags: numpy

Let's say I want to sample `0` with probability `p0 = 0.5`, `1` with probability `p1 = 0.3`, or a `2` with probability `p2 = 0.2`. This is fairly simple to do:

```
p0 = 0.5
p1 = 0.3
p2 = 0.2
idx = np.random.choice(3, p=[p0, p1, p2])
```

Now, lets say I want to repeat this process `N`, each times using different probabilities. Something like:

```
N = 4
p0 = np.array([0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])
p1 = np.array([0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1])
p2 = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1])
idx = np.empty(N)

for i in range(N):
    idx[i] = np.random.choice(3, p=[p0[i], p1[i], p2[i]])
```

However, this is obviously slow. Ideally I'd like to do this avoiding loops. Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: This looks like the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237596/how-to-improve-np-random-choice-looping-efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to generate a uniform random array of size `N`, compare that to the accumulate probabilities, then take the indexes of the first `True` value in each column:

```
cum_probs = np.cumsum([p0,p1,p2],axis=0)
idx = np.argmax(np.random.uniform(size=N) < cum_probs, axis=0)
```

Comment: Neat! One typo -- I believe the last line should be "axis=0"

Comment: @Xanshiz yes, you're correct. Updated.