# Bootstrap sampling in Pandas with weighting on multiple levels

Tags: pandas, group-by, sampling, statistics-bootstrap

### Bootstrap sampling in Pandas with weighting on multiple levels

Given a table as the one in the example below (*with possible additional columns*), I want to bootstrap samples where `countries` and `fruits` are sampled ***independently uniformly*** at random.

For each `country`, there is a number of `fruits`, a number that varies between `countries`.

To make it clear what I am looking for, I have created a series **(1-4)** of sampling strategies, starting simple and getting more and more towards what I want:

Sample *M* fruits per country ...

1. ... uniformly.
2. ... inversely proportional to the number of occurrences of the fruit.
3. ... (on average) uniformly, but bootstrap the countries.
4. ... (on average) inversely proportional to the number of occurrences of the fruit, but bootstrap the countries.

---

As a minimal example for my question, I have chosen `countries` and `fruits`.

```
| Country |   Fruit    |
| ------- | ---------- |
| USA     | Pineapple  |
| USA     | Apple      |
| Canada  | Watermelon |
| Canada  | Banana     |
| Canada  | Apple      |
| Mexico  | Cherry     |
| Mexico  | Apple      |
| Mexico  | Apple      |
| ...     | ...        |
```

###### Create example data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([
        ['USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'Mexico', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'UK', 'UK', 'France', 'France', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'Spain'],
        ['Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Orange', 'Watermelon', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Blueberry', 'Cherry', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Blueberry', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Cherry', 'Blueberry', 'Pineapple', 'Pineapple', 'Watermelon', 'Pineapple', 'Watermelon', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Blueberry'],
    ]).T,
        columns=['Country', 'Fruit'],
).set_index('Country')
df['other columns'] = '...'
```

###### Setup:

```py
M = 10  # number of fruits to sample per country
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123)  # set seed for reproducibility

# create weights for later use
fruit_weights = 1 / df.groupby('Fruit').size().rename('fruit_weights')
country_weights = 1 / df.groupby('Country').size().rename('country_weights')

# normalize weights to sum to 1
fruit_weights /= fruit_weights.sum()
country_weights /= country_weights.sum()
```

###### (1) Sample *M* fruits per country *uniformly*:

```py
sampled_fruits = df.groupby('Country').sample(n=M, replace=True, random_state=rng)
```

###### (2) Sample *M* fruits per country *inversely proportional to the number of occurrences* of the fruit:

```py
df2 = df.join(fruit_weights, on='Fruit')  # add weights to a copy of the original dataframe
sampled_fruits = df2.groupby('Country').sample(
    n=M,
    replace=True,
    random_state=rng,
    weights='fruit_weights',
)
```

###### (3) Sample *M* fruits per country (*on average*) *uniformly*, but *bootstrap* the countries:

```py
sampled_fruits = pd.concat(
    {
        s: df.sample(
            n=df.index.nunique(),  # number of countries
            weights=country_weights,
            replace=True,
            random_state=rng,
        )
        for s in range(M)
    },
    names=['sample', 'Country'],
).reset_index('sample')
```

###### (4) Sample *M* fruits per country (*on average*) *inversely proportional to the number of occurrences* of the fruit, but *bootstrap* the countries:

```py
df4 = df.join(fruit_weights, on='Fruit')

# normalize fruit weights to sum to 1 per country to not affect the country weights
df4['fruit_weights'] = df4.fruit_weights.groupby('Country').transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())

df4 = df4.join(country_weights, on='Country')

weight_cols = [c for c in df4.columns if '_weights' in c]
weights = df4[weight_cols].prod(axis=1)
df4 = df4.drop(columns=weight_cols)
sampled_fruits = pd.concat(
    {
        s: df4.sample(
            n=df.index.nunique(),  # number of countries
            weights=weights,
            replace=True,
            random_state=rng,
        )
        for s in range(M)
    },
    names=['sample', 'Country'],
).reset_index('sample')
```

Number **(4)** ***almost*** accomplishes what I want. The `countries` and `fruits` are sampled independently uniformly at random.

There is only ***one issue***:

Assume now that I also want to sample `vegetables` and then (*somehow*) compare the results to the results from the `fruits`. Assume that the `countries` remain the same, but the number of different `vegetables` is ***not*** equal to the number of different `fruits`, neither overall, nor for a given country (*at least not for all countries*).

This will result in different sets of `countries` being sampled for `fruits` and `vegetables` for any given bootstrap iteration [image: formula]. To clarify, for each bootstrap iteration [image: formula], the sampled `countries` should be identical for `fruits` and `vegetables`, i.e.

```py
for m in range(M):
    assert all(sampled_fruits[sampled_fruits['sample'] == m].index == sampled_vegetables[sampled_vegetables['sample'] == m].index)
```

---

(*I know how to achieve the result I want using nested for-loops, sampling a `country` followed by a `fruit`/`vegetable`, but this is something I want to avoid.*)

---

(*The* `fruits` *and* `vegetables` *are just random things chosen to illustrate my question. In my real use case, the* `countries` *are samples in a test set, and the* `fruits` *and* `vegetables` *are two different groups of humans, where each human has assessed / made predictions on a subset of the test set.*)

---

Comment: I can think of a way which doesn't involve a for loop, which is to construct a probability matrix which specifies for each country the probability of choosing a fruit, then use np.random.randint to index into the country axis of that matrix, then do a [vectorized weighted selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187130/fast-random-weighted-selection-across-all-rows-of-a-stochastic-matrix) on the resulting matrix, but it's not clear that would actually be faster than a for loop. Would depend on the cardinality of fruits/vegetables vs countries.

Comment: Some suggestions which on how to make this question easier to answer: 1) You know how to do the fruit/vegetable sampling with a for loop - why not show it? 2) If this is a performance concern, then make that an explicit criteria. Benchmark your slow solution and invite people to improve on it. There may be a better solution involving a for loop than one without.