# Select random row based on intervals

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a function in Python Pandas which randomly selects a row based on the values from a column in a dataframe (Function to perform [roulette wheel selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection))?

i.e.

```
 id     value
 1      1
 2      2
 3      3
```

Then with chance 1/(1+2+3) row 1 is selected, chance 2/6 row 2 and 3/6 row 3.

I know it is easy to write your own function with a random number between 0 and sum(value) and for loop and then select the row but I was wondering if there was a pre-defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select an index with something like:

i = choice(range(len(df)), df.value)

where `choice` is whatever you want from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803135/weighted-choice-short-and-simple).

Then use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).