# Generating random numbers with weighted probabilities in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, probability

Given a positive integer array `a`, the goal is to generate 5 random numbers based on the weight they have in the array.

For example:

```
a = [2,3,4,4,4,4,4,6,7,8,9]
```

In this case the number 4 has appeared 5 times, in this case the number 4 should have the probability of 5/11 to appear.

No numbers should be repeated.

Comment: What do you mean without repetition? In that can it does not preserve the weights. Do you mean without repetition of the index?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear, but if you mean what I think you mean, here's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803135/weighted-choice-short-and-simple

Comment: are you after `np.random.choice(list(set(a)), size=5,replace=False)`?

Comment: By doing list(set(a)) you are removing the weights. 
The thing is that i don't have calculated the Weights as they have it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803135/weighted-choice-short-and-simple I have the weights as the repeated numbers @ajcr you are right but i dont have the probability of each value

Comment: @Charlie: ah I see, so given `a`, do you want to calculate the weights and then use the random choice function?

Comment: @ajcr you are right :)

Comment: @Charlie: are the values in your array always positive integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `a`, an array of positive integers, you'll first need to compute the frequency of each integer. For example, using `bincount`:

```
>>> a = [2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,9,2,3,6,3,1]
>>> b = np.bincount(a)
```

`b` tells you the frequency of each integer in `a`. The corresponding set of weights is therefore the array `b/len(a)`. Using `np.random.choice` with these weights and `replace=False` should then give you what you need:

```
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(len(b)), 5, p=b/len(a), replace=False)
array([5, 9, 4, 3, 8])
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(len(b)), 5, p=b/len(a), replace=False)
array([7, 4, 6, 9, 1])
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(len(b)), 5, p=b/len(a), replace=False)
array([3, 7, 4, 9, 6])
```

If you're not working with only positive integers, or if you are working with large positive integers, @user2357112 points out in the comments below that `np.unique` provides another solution. Here you'd write:

```
>>> choices, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
>>> np.random.choice(choices, 5, p=counts/len(a), replace=False)
array([9, 8, 2, 4, 5])
```

Comment: You could also use [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with the `return_counts` option, which works much better when your input isn't a bunch of nonnegative integers or `max(a)` is large.

Comment: Thanks - I always seem to forget about the `return_counts` parameter - that would indeed be much better in the cases you've mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible to update it to this example? a =[(23, 11), (10, 16), (13, 11), (12, 3), (4, 15), (10, 16), (10, 16)] b = Counter(elem for elem in a) c = len(a) 
@ajcr

Comment: @Charlie: I'd argue that your updated question is different enough to warrant asking a completely new question (list of integers vs. Counter object with tuples as keys). It's probably best to leave *this* page about the list of integers because it's probably the most common case and likely to be of help to future readers. If you ask a new question about Counter objects, I'll gladly take a look and try to answer it as best I can.

Comment: @ajcr i have updated the question, this is the other one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934540/generate-a-list-of-random-weighted-tuples-from-a-list) BTW thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for `numpy.random.multinomial`
For example `np.random.multinomial(1, [1/6.]*6, size=1)`  is throwing fair dice once. 
After you get an result you can update probability vector(must sum to 1) as you desire. For example `numpy.random.multinomial(1, [1/2., 1/2., 0., 0., 0., 0.], size=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (and perhaps most inefficient) can be as follows:

```
import random
def get_randoms(n, a):
    a = a[:]
    r = []
    for i in range(n):
        r.append(random.choice(a))
        a = [y for y in a if y != r[-1]]
    return r

print get_randoms(5, [2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,9,2,3,6,3,1])
```

The output can would be something like

```
[8, 2, 3, 6, 9]
```