# Generate a list of random weighted tuples from a list

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, probability

Given a tuple list `a`:

```
a =[(23, 11), (10, 16), (13, 11),  (12, 3), (4, 15), (10, 16), (10, 16)]
```

We can count how many appearances of each tuple we have using `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> b = Counter(a)
>>> b
Counter({(4, 15): 1, (10, 16): 3, (12, 3): 1, (13, 11): 1, (23, 11): 1}
```

Now, the idea is to select 3 random tuples from the list, *without repetition*, such that the count determines the probability that a particular tuple is chosen.

For instance, `(10, 16)` is more likely to be chosen than the others - its weight is 3/7 while the other four tuples have weight 1/7.

I have tried to use `np.random.choice`:

```
a[np.random.choice(len(a), 3, p=b/len(a))]
```

But I'm not able to generate the tuples.

Im trying:

```
a =[(23, 11), (10, 16), (13, 11),  (10, 16), (10, 16), (10, 16), (10, 16)]
b = Counter(a)
c = []
print "counter list"
print b
for item in b:
    print "item from current list"
    print item
    print "prob of the item"
    print (float(b[item])/float(len(a)))

    c.append(float(b[item])/float(len(a)))

print "prob list"
print c

print (np.random.choice(np.arange(len(b)), 3, p=c, replace=False))
```

In this case im getting the random indexes of the array.

- Is there any more optimized way not to have to calculate the
  probabilities array?
- Also there is an issue that is that the prob array does not correspond to the Counter array.

Comment: Are duplicate tuples allowed?

Comment: Link to related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34904122/3923281

Comment: @Charlie - I edited some details into your question based on your previous question (I think it should be clearer to those have not read that other question now.)

Comment: @ajcr I found a way to do it but the counter array when iterating is returning the values in an odd order..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

listOfNumbers =[(23, 11), (10, 16), (13, 11),  (10, 16), (10, 16), (10, 16), (10, 16)]
b = Counter(listOfNumbers)
c = []
pres=[]
for k,v in b.most_common():
    c.append(float(v)/float(len(listOfNumbers)))
    pres.append(k)

resultIndex = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(b)), 3, p=c, replace=False)

ass=[]
for res in resultIndex:
    ass.append(pres[res])

print ass
```

Now is just to see if is there any way to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't interested in the intermediate step of calculating frequencies, you could use random.shuffle (either on the list or a copy) and then slice off as many items as you need.

e.g.

```
import random
a =[(23, 11), (10, 16), (13, 11),  (12, 3), (4, 15), (10, 16), (10, 16)]
random.shuffle(a)
random_sample = a[0:3]
print(random_sample)
```

As shuffle reorders in place it will avoid the repetition issue, and statistically should give the same result (excluding differences in random number generation between np and random).

Comment: Actually this is not following the definition of not having repeated items this can produce i.e. [(10, 16), (10, 16), (23, 11)]

Comment: I've interpreted no repetition to mean each item in the original list can only sampled once.  If you are sampling from the reduced list with probabilities then I think you would need to recalculate the distribution each time an item is removed?

3/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7 -> 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4 if (10,16) is removed
3/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7, 1/7 -> 3/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6 if any other removed

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the following steps 3 times:

1. Randomly chose a number `i` in range `[0..n-1]` where `n` is a current number of elements in `a`.
2. Find a `tuple` on `i`-th position in the initial `a` list. Add `tuple` to resulting triplet.
3. Remove all occurrences of `tuple` from `a`.

Pay attention to a corner case when `a` can be empty.

The overall time complexity will be **O(n)** for a list.

On the first step number `i` should be generated according to uniform distribution which regular `random` provides. The more occurrences of a particular tuple are in `a` the more likely it will be chosen.