# Python random list-index with probability

Tags: python

How can I write a function that gives me the random-index of a list-element, but based on the probabilities in the list?

The list looks like this with 5 elements.

```
a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
```

Is there a simple and fast solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803135/weighted-choice-short-and-simple

Comment: Not a duplicate. The question has some different particulars.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a job for [Numpy's `numpy.random.choice()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.7.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), and its `p` parameter:

> ```
> p : 1-D array-like, optional
>
> The probabilities associated with each entry in a. If not given,
> the sample assumes a uniform distribtion over all entries in a.
> ```

So if there's only one list (where an element is both the probability of each element, and the element itself to be selected, you can do it like this:

```
from numpy.random import choice

elementsAndProbabilities = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]

randomElement = choice(elementsAndProbabilities, p=elementsAndProbabilities)
print randomElement
```

If you have a list of elements and a list of probabilities for each element (separate), you can do it like this:

```
from numpy.random import choice

elements = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"]
probabilities = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]    

randomElement = choice(elements, p=probabilities)
print randomElement
```

Now, you said you wanted the *index*, not the element, so we can get the index like this:

```
from numpy.random import choice

probabilities = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]

randomElement = choice(range(len(probabilities)), p=probabilities)
print randomElement
```

Answer (score 3):

NumPy will probably be faster if you have it, but if not, here's a pure Python solution.

```
from random import random

a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]

def randombin(bins):
    r = random()
    p = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(bins):
        p += v
        if r < p:
           return i
    # p may not equal exactly 1.0 due to floating-point rounding errors
    # so if we get here, just try again (the errors are small, so this
    # should not happen very often).  You could also just put it in the
    # last bin or pick a bin at random, depending on your tolerance for
    # small biases
    return randombin(bins)

print randombin(a)
```