# Picking from Dictionary probablity wise

Tags: python, dictionary, probability

Let's say I have a dictionary

```
{'us': 
     {'male': 
            {'given_names': 
                          ['Alex', 'Bob', 'Charlie'] 
            }, 
      'female': 
            {'given_names': 
                          ['Alice', 'Betty', 'Claire'] 
            } 
      },

'uk': 
     {'male': 
            {'given_names': 
                          ['aaa', 'Bbb', 'cc'] 
            }, 
      'female': 
            {'given_names': 
                          ['ppp', 'ddd', 'sss'] 
            } 
      }

}
```

Now let's say I want to get 60% US names, 40% UK names, but with 50 50 % males and females names.

How Can I do it?

Current approach? Trying to think something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927221/how-to-choose-keys-from-a-python-dictionary-based-on-weighted-probability)
But I guess it is more complex then that.

I was thinking to get all the names first, then applying a distribution from them? But it is not making some logical sense. Can someone help?

```
        # all_possible_names = [
        #     name
        #     for list_of_names in [
        #         self.library[area][gender][
        #             "given_names"
        #         ]
        #         for gender in self.genders
        #         for area in self.name_areas
        #     ]
        #     for name in list_of_names
        # ]
        # print(all_possible_names) `
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your current attempt(s)?

Comment: My current attempt does nothing, I was thinking to get all the names first via this code which I have edited in question.

Comment: Can a given name from either level be picked more than once?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your expected output would be?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, it wont be a problem if it is picked more than once.

Comment: @JonClements a list like ['name1', 'name2', .... 'namen'] where n is total number of names we want but following the probability distribution.

Comment: Use "random.choices" where each name gets a weight which is the probability of the country ("us" names get 0.6 as weight). If the gender distribution wouldn't be 50:50 multiply the weight by the desired probability of the gender.

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you provide a small example with regards to this data?

Comment: `random.choices(['Alex', 'ppp', 'Alice', 'aaa'], [0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4])`

Comment: How will the male-female distribution that is 50% will play in this case?

Comment: For 50:50 you would multiply all weights with 0.5 but multiplying all weights with the same positive number doesn't change anything (except for rounding errors) so it can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `random.choices` with a weight and `choice` to split between male/female, assuming your dictionary is named `d` and `N` is the total amount of names you'd like, then:

```
from random import choice, choices

N = 3

names = [
    choice(d[country][choice(['male', 'female'])]['given_names'])
    for country in choices(['us', 'uk'], weights=[0.6, 0.4])
    for _ in range(N)
]
```

Comment: this seems great(Will test in a bit).  just a quick question if I want to change the distribution of male and female, i simply have to set a weights for them right? i.e `choice(['male', 'female'], weights=[0.4, 0.6])`?
Right?

Comment: @AhmadAnis `choice` doesn't accept weights... use `choices` instead

Comment: I hope the above code will work with `choices(['male', 'female'], weights=[0.4, 0.6])`

Comment: @Ahmad it should - just try it out :)

Comment: I do have a question here. `for _ in range(N)` for each iteration in N I am getting a single country so I suppose it is making a random choice once. Can this behaviour be changed to let it make choice in each iteration in N?

Comment: I removed the `for _ in range(N)` part and added the `k=N` in `choices(['us', 'uk'])` part. I hope it does not affect the logic I want.

Comment: @AhmadAnis well... that's for you to decide I guess? :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's random.choice to do the weight distribution

```py
from numpy.random import choice as npchoice
from random import choice


some_dict = {
    "us": {
        "male": {"given_names": ["Alex", "Bob", "Charlie"]},
        "female": {"given_names": ["Alice", "Betty", "Claire"]},
    },
    "uk": {
        "male": {"given_names": ["aaa", "Bbb", "cc"]},
        "female": {"given_names": ["ppp", "ddd", "sss"]},
    },
}


possible_choices = ["us", "uk"]
probability_distribution = [0.6, 0.4]
number_of_items_to_pick = 200
countries = list(
    npchoice(possible_choices, number_of_items_to_pick, p=probability_distribution)
)
print(countries)


names = []
females = 0
males = 0
for country in countries:
    gender = choice(["male", "female"])
    if gender == "female":
        females += 1
    else:
        males += 1
    name = choice(some_dict[country][gender]["given_names"])
    names.append(name)
    print(f"{country} | {gender:.1} | {name}")


print(f"\nF: {females}  | M: {males}")
print(f"US: {countries.count('us')} | UK: {countries.count('uk')}")
```

I added some logic above for my testing, and to check the distribution.
It can be shortened to the logic below:

```py
from numpy.random import choice as npchoice
from random import choice

names = [
    choice(some_dict[country][choice(["male", "female"])]["given_names"])
    for country in npchoice(["us", "uk"], 200, p=[0.6, 0.4])
]
```

Comment: Hi, Edo thanks for your answer. It is working well.