# Write a C++ program to generate random distribution between 0 to 5 given rand1() which returns 0 or 1 at random

Tags: algorithm, probability

Given a function

```
int rand1();
```

which return 0 or 1,  with equal probability,
implement a function

```
int rand5();
```

which returns 0,1,2,3,4,5   with equal probability.

!!! Twist !!!  Read before marking it as duplicate...

Number of times you can call rand1() is fixed. You may decide it to be 10 or 20 or 100 for that matter, but NOT any number of rand1() calls.
i.e.  there is a upper limit on on number of rand1() calls. 
Also you have to guarantee that rand5() should always return o to 5, with equal probability. It is not acceptable that the code is skewed towards, few extra 0 and 1.

If you think it is NOT POSSIBLE to write such function, then you can let us all know, as to why it is not possible.

EDIT : 
this is what i have, which I think is not sufficient

```
int rand5()
{
bitset<3> b;
b[0] = rand1();
b[1] = rand1();
b[2] = rand1();
int i = b;
if(b >= 6)
 return rand5();
return i;
}
```

Comment: What has this to do with C++ or C?

Comment: well you have to write the code in C++ or SOME LANGUAGE . If I say you  dont have to write code, then the question will be closed as NOT related to programming. There are many people waiting to do just that.  But the fact is I have to implement this code (in C++), to do just the same. I have a sub-optimal solution with no fixed upper bound on calls of rand1(), and I am searching for implementation which doesnt have that limitation.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ??

Comment: Sounds like homework. Please add the word "homework" to the title, and show what  you have so far. Explain what your problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random number from specified discrete distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207238/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-specified-discrete-distribution)

Comment: @Ajeet Rather than just post the problem, show us what you have so far or where you're specifically stuck. Also, retagging as 'homework'.

Comment: This may be more suitable for statistics.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @Ajeet: That you will be writing it in C++ is not particularly relevant; you are not ready to implement this algorithm yet. You are still trying to _design_ it (mathematically), which has nothing at all to do with C++.

Comment: @Alf P : This is a homework ?   Why dont you try solving it ?  I doubt this tough question would become homework .
IMHO This is something that will separate a veteran programmer from learnt-ten-program-answers-yesterday.

Comment: @Ajeet: If it's not homework, remove the `homework` tag. And don't mind Alf; he thinks _everything_'s homework :P

Comment: @Ajeet: the question is trivial, not tough.

Comment: @Alf : So you solved it ?  Please please give the answer. May be I am not smart enough to understand the difference between trivial and tough.

Comment: @Ajeet: fishing for answers won't help you. i suggest you just think about it. e.g. think about how an ordinary random generator works.

Comment: @Tomalak : I didnt put homework tag. :( Jared Ng  did that.
But thanks Tomalak. :)

Comment: @Alf : dude, I dont get it. Are we all not on stack-exchange for "answers" ? Pardon me but I agree my thinking phase was really short and I couldnt come up with answer for that.

Comment: @Ajeet I'm sorry, your question did look very much like homework. In the future, please try to include some explanation of what you've attempted, or where exactly you're stuck. Posting a question that reads "Implement this" doesn't show the effort you've made on your part.

Comment: While impossible to get a finite solution in the worst case, it is quite possible on average.  Here is one which takes on average 11/3 iterations.  I am sure that it is possible to to do better though:  `int rand5() {
    int b = 0;
    while(rand1() == b) {
        b ^= 1;
    }
    return 3*rand1() + (b ? 2 : rand1());
}`

Comment: @Jared : Point taken. Next time I will post the existing solution which I want to improve upon.

Comment: @Ajeet: check for solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128608

Comment: @joe: While a good puzzle for [CodeGolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) could be constructed from this question, in it's current form it is nor even remotely suitable. //doffs CodeGolf.SE moderator hat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible. You can't divide 2^n into 6 evenly.

Comment: ...which is only required because of the fixed calls to `rand1()`.  Otherwise you could generate 3 bits and simply discard any 6 and 7 results and re-roll.

Comment: So far my conclusion too. But problem is I have no way of knowing that  this is definitive. May be there are other ways to generate this distribution.

Comment: Of course there are other ways to generate the distribution. They simply are not compatible with a fixed number of calls to rand1().

Answer (score 0):

This is what people are doing (whether they know it or not) when they generate a random integer in the range [0, N) from a random floating-point number in the range [0, 1):

```
// assumed sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(float) == 32/CHAR_BIT
// assumed 'float' is IEEE single precision with the mantissa in the
// low bits
unsigned int randN(unsigned int high)
{
    union { unsigned int i; float f; } u;

    u.i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
        u.i = u.i*2 + rand1();

    // u.f will be in the range [0, 0.5)
    // so multiply by twice the desired range
    return (unsigned int)floor(u.f * (high * 2));
}
```

I suspect this does not produce a *perfectly* uniform distribution, but it's good enough for most purposes.

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to just making a random *n* bit number modulo 6 and accepting the slight bias that occurs because 2^*n* is not divisible by 6.  The larger *n* the smaller the error.  The use of `float` just obfuscates this slightly.

Comment: Yah.  I used `float` because, as I said, it's pretty common to generate a random integer in `[0, N)` from a RNG primitive that produces a random float in `[0, 1)` by exactly this method, accepting any bias.  I'm sort of curious what the bias winds up looking like, but not curious enough to actually do the math.