# Randomly selecting points in a plane, with a higher probability of selection given to closer points

Tags: java, random, probability

I've got a problem I'm not too sure how to solve.  I have a 2d space with several points in it.  I also have a current point, which is one of the points in the space.  I want to randomly select one of the other point, with a higher probability for selection being given to points closer to my current point.  I'm working in Java.  Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: What sort of probabilistic bias are you looking for? Does the actual distance matter, or do you only care about ordering by distance?

Comment: Actual distance would matter.  I want the random selection to favour points that are closer in an euclidian distance sort of way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Assign a "weight" to each point by for instance computing `1 / distanceFromCurrent`.
2. Select a point based on these weights.

Solution for the latter part can for instance be found in some of the following answers:

- [Weighted random map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027421/weighted-random-map)
- [Random value from enum with probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269250/random-value-from-enum-with-probability)
- [Select k random elements from a list whose elements have weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140787/select-random-k-elements-from-a-list-whose-elements-have-weights)

---

Another option would be to use [`java.util.Random.nextGaussian`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29). Adjust the resulting double so that it represents a reasonable radius, and select the neighboring point closest to this radius.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I suppose the actual task of choosing a point from the set of weights could be a whole different issue on its own.

Answer (score 1):

you alraedy have all the elements ^^

what you want is that the further away from the current point the less probability it has therefore you want to use a formula where the distance decreases the probability like:

> 1/d

d being the distance between your current point and another.

so what you do with that is calculate for each point their probability 1/d and sum up all these probabilities to get you your total or world.

so something like:

```
total = 0;
for(MyPoint p : list){
   p.probability = 1/(distance(currentpoint,p);
   total += p.probability;
}
```

and then you need only to do

```
Math.random*total;
```

and compare it to your list of points ^^;

Jason

Comment: Thanks, this was also really useful.  I think this is an instance of the type of solution aioobe talked about, but it helped me understand how I am going to actually implement the solution.

Comment: yep aioobe gave you the shorter version but its the same logic ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need some probability distribution that is a function of distance, more specifically, you need the CDF or the inverse-CDF of the probability distribution as a java function

```
/**
 * @param distance
 * @return probability of choosing a point closer than distance
**/
double someCDF( double distance );
```

One possible choice is the exponential distribution, and the corresponding CDF would be `1-Math.exp( distance * r )` where `r` is some constant for scaling. Again, there are lots of different functions you could use, but this one is really easy to code up.

Then sort the points by distance, and

```
double rnum = Math.random();
for( Point point : sortedPoints )
    if( someCDF( distance(thisPoint,point) ) >= rnum )
        return point;
```

would give you the point you want (technically the first point whose probability to be picked is less than or equal to 1-the uniform random number, which you can prove gives you back the probability distribution of the inverse CDF in the long run.)