# How do you calculate N random numbers that are weighted without repeats in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, sample

I'm trying to calculate 5 numbers at random. The numbers 1-35 have set probability weights that are assigned to each number. I'm wondering how, in Matlab, to compute 5 random numbers with weights WITHOUT repeats. Also seeking how to compute 5 sets of those.

Comment: @excaza I've already looked at that but that allows for repeats

Comment: What you could do is generate a vector with all repeats, for ex [1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4] and then shuffle it. Then use each element in order.

Comment: Check [`datasample`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html)

Answer (score 2):

Although I would suspect MATLAB has a built in function for this, the documentation for `randsample` suggests otherwise:

> `Y = randsample(N,K,true,W)` or `randsample(POPULATION,K,true,W)` returns a
>       weighted sample, using positive weights W, taken with replacement.  W is
>       often a vector of probabilities. **This function does not support weighted
>       sampling without replacement.**

So, instead, since you only are looking for a few numbers, looping isn't a terrible idea:

```
POP = 1:35;
W = rand(1,35); W=W/sum(W);
k = 5;

mynumbers = zeros(1,k);
for i=1:k
    mynumbers(i)    = randsample(POP,1,true,W);
    idx2remove      = find(POP==mynumbers(i));
    POP(idx2remove) = [];
    W(idx2remove)   = [];
end
```

The entries in `W` are your weights. The vector `POP` is your number 1 through 35. The number `k` is how many you'd like to choose.

The loop randomly samples one number (with weights) at a time using MATLAB's `randsample`, then the selected number and corresponding weight are removed from `POP` and `W`.

For larger `k` I hope there's a better solution...

Comment: Just found duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205443/weighted-sampling-without-replacement)

Comment: Holy nuts, Thanks! Quick question. I'm horribly new to matlab and I'm honestly just using it for this specific problem in my life. So I don't understand quite what you're doing in your for loop. (i.e., where do i put in my assigned weights). Sorry, just horribly new to this!

Comment: another follow up in addition to the previous, is there any way to generate 5 different vectors of 5?

Comment: Yes to your first question, for your second, wrap the code in Geoff''s answer in another `for` loop.

Comment: @David, have no idea how to do that, painfully new to coding and I'm only using this for a specific project at work, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Try this Getting Started with MATLAB http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html

Comment: Also in the documentation: `To randomly sample data, with or without replacement, use datasample.`

Comment: but you couldn't just tell me how to do the second forloop? Some buddies and I are playing around with something and this would be a huge help.