# Pythonic way to select list elements with different probability

Tags: python

```
import random
pos = ["A", "B", "C"]
x = random.choice["A", "B", "C"]
```

This code gives me either "A", "B" or "C" with equal probability.
Is there a nice way to express it when you want "A" with 30%, "B" with 40% and "C" with 30% probability?

Comment: Searching found several similar/identical questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526255/probability-distribution-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056151/random-python-dictionary-key-weighted-by-values)

Comment: @ma3: One of the weak points of this site is that as old questions tend to be ignored, there's no mechanism or motivation to improve on them.  I think my answer is significantly better than at least the higher answers on those questions--havn't read the lower ones--but nobody would ever see it if I posted it on those.

Comment: Starting with Python 3.6 you can use `random.choices` to submit a list of weights/probabilities.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Weights define a probability distribution function (pdf). Random numbers from any such pdf can be generated by [applying its associated inverse cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Non-uniform_generators) to uniform random numbers between 0 and 1.

See also this [SO explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977354/generating-non-uniform-random-numbers/977508#977508), or, as explained by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative%5Fdistribution%5Ffunction#Inverse):

> If Y has a U[0,1] distribution then F⁻¹(Y) is distributed as F. This is
>   used in random number generation using
>   the inverse transform sampling-method.

```
import random
import bisect
import collections

def cdf(weights):
    total = sum(weights)
    result = []
    cumsum = 0
    for w in weights:
        cumsum += w
        result.append(cumsum / total)
    return result

def choice(population, weights):
    assert len(population) == len(weights)
    cdf_vals = cdf(weights)
    x = random.random()
    idx = bisect.bisect(cdf_vals, x)
    return population[idx]

weights=[0.3, 0.4, 0.3]
population = 'ABC'
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i in range(10000):
    counts[choice(population, weights)] += 1
print(counts)

# % test.py
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 3066, 'C': 2964, 'B': 3970})
```

The `choice` function above uses `bisect.bisect`, so selection of a weighted random variable is done in `O(log n)` where `n` is the length of `weights`.

---

Note that as of version 1.7.0, NumPy has a Cythonized [np.random.choice function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). For example, this generates 1000 samples from the population `[0,1,2,3]` with weights `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(4, 1000, p=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
```

`np.random.choice` also has a `replace` parameter for sampling with or without replacement.

---

A theoretically better algorithm is the [Alias Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method). It builds a table which requires `O(n)` time, but after that,  samples can be drawn in `O(1)` time. So, if you need to draw many samples, in theory the Alias Method may be faster. There is a Python implementation of the Walker Alias Method [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576564-walkers-alias-method-for-random-objects-with-diffe/), and a [numpy version here](https://gist.github.com/ntamas/1109133).

Answer (score 30):

Not... so much...

```
pos = ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 4 + ['C'] * 3
print random.choice(pos)
```

or

```
pos = {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 3}
print random.choice([x for x in pos for y in range(pos[x])])
```

Comment: If the ratios are from user input this is potentially dangerous, eg. 99.999999%/0.000001%.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow incorporate the dictionary into `random.choice()`?

Comment: @SomeGuy: `random.choice()` takes a sequence.

Comment: So, in other words, I could?

Comment: @SomeGuy: You would need to convert the dictionary into a sequence. Like how my second bit of code does.

Comment: This is one of the most elegant answers I've seen, but unfortunately it does not work if the weights are not integers :(

Comment: Good approach if the weights are given as small integers. If the weights are floats with 3 digit precision, they have to be multiplied by 10^3, creating a  big array and inefficient sampling

Answer (score 9):

Here's a class to expose a bunch of items with relative probabilities, without actually expanding the list:

```
import bisect
class WeightedTuple(object):
    """
    >>> p = WeightedTuple({'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 3})
    >>> len(p)
    6
    >>> p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]
    ('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C')
    >>> p[-1], p[-2], p[-3], p[-4], p[-5], p[-6]
    ('C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A')
    >>> p[6]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    IndexError
    >>> p[-7]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    IndexError
    """
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.indexes = []
        self.items = []
        next_index = 0
        for key in sorted(items.keys()):
            val = items[key]
            self.indexes.append(next_index)
            self.items.append(key)
            next_index += val

        self.len = next_index

    def __getitem__(self, n):
        if n < 0:
            n = self.len + n
        if n < 0 or n >= self.len:
            raise IndexError

        idx = bisect.bisect_right(self.indexes, n)
        return self.items[idx-1]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
```

Now, just say:

```
data = WeightedTuple({'A': 30, 'B': 40, 'C': 30})
random.choice(data)
```

Comment: Note that I only sorted the keys before inserting (rather than just using `items.iteritems`) so it would have deterministic output, which makes the doctests simpler.

Comment: Note that I avoided floating-point: if something can be done clearly with integers, it avoids any question of rounding error affecting the output, and it's much easier for the doctest to be comprehensive.  Also, this doesn't care what the sum of the values is, eg. it's implicitly normalizing.  For example, if you're picking from a list of weighted mirrors and you disable one of them, you don't have to adjust all of the rest so the weights add up to 1.

Comment: Note that `sorted(dict.keys())` is a little redundant. `sorted(d)` does the same thing with one list less.

Comment: I wrote a similar class based on this one, in Objective-C http://stackoverflow.com/a/22243637/129202

Answer (score 8):

As of [Python 3.6, there is `random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) for that.

**original answer from 2010**:

You can also make use this form, which does not create a list arbitrarily big (and can work with either integral or decimal probabilities):

```
pos = [("A", 30), ("B", 40), ("C", 30)]


from random import uniform
def w_choice(seq):
    total_prob = sum(item[1] for item in seq)
    chosen = random.uniform(0, total_prob)
    cumulative = 0
    for item, probality in seq:
        cumulative += probality
        if cumulative > chosen:
            return item
```

Comment: This can be further optimised by using bisect.bisect to identify the option - instead of iterating through all options. This reduces the iteration from O(N) to O(logN) where N is the number of the options.

Answer (score 5):

There are some good solutions offered here, but I would suggest that you look at [Eli Bendersky's thorough discussion](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/) of this issue, which compares various algorithms to achieve this (with implementations in Python) before choosing one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random
from decimal import Decimal

pos = {'A': Decimal("0.3"), 'B': Decimal("0.4"), 'C': Decimal("0.3")}
choice = random.random()
F_x = 0
for k, p in pos.iteritems():
    F_x += p
    if choice <= F_x:
        x = k
        break
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot convert float to Decimal.  First convert the float to a string`