# Applying Sklearn Gaussian Mixture algorithm to fit GM curves

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have been looking at the Sklearn library and it seems to be very accurate in fitting wide components in [gaussian mixtures distributions](http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.html):

[image]

I would like to try this methodology for my astronomical data (modifying it a bit since the previous example is deprecated and it will not work in the current version)

However, in my data I have a curve of data and not a distribution of points. Consequently, I generate a distribution from the numpy random.choice function to generate a distribution weighted by the shape of my curve. Afterwards I run sklearn fit:

```
import numpy            as np
from sklearn.mixture    import GMM, GaussianMixture
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats        import norm

#Raw data
data = np.array([[6535.62597656, 7.24362260936e-17],
        [6536.45898438, 6.28683338273e-17],
        [6537.29248047, 5.84596729207e-17],
        [6538.12548828, 8.13193914837e-17],
        [6538.95849609, 6.70583742068e-17],
        [6539.79199219, 7.8511483881e-17],
        [6540.625, 9.22121293063e-17],
        [6541.45800781, 7.81353615478e-17],
        [6542.29150391, 8.58095991639e-17],
        [6543.12451172, 9.30569784967e-17],
        [6543.95800781, 9.92541957936e-17],
        [6544.79101562, 1.1682282379e-16],
        [6545.62402344, 1.21238102142e-16],
        [6546.45751953, 1.51062780724e-16],
        [6547.29052734, 1.92193416858e-16],
        [6548.12402344, 2.12669644265e-16],
        [6548.95703125, 1.89356624109e-16],
        [6549.79003906, 1.62571112976e-16],
        [6550.62353516, 1.73262984876e-16],
        [6551.45654297, 1.79300635724e-16],
        [6552.29003906, 1.93990357551e-16],
        [6553.12304688, 2.15530881856e-16],
        [6553.95605469, 2.13273711105e-16],
        [6554.78955078, 3.03175829363e-16],
        [6555.62255859, 3.17610250166e-16],
        [6556.45556641, 3.75917668914e-16],
        [6557.2890625, 4.64631505826e-16],
        [6558.12207031, 6.9828152092e-16],
        [6558.95556641, 1.19680535606e-15],
        [6559.78857422, 2.18677945421e-15],
        [6560.62158203, 4.07692754678e-15],
        [6561.45507812, 5.89089137849e-15],
        [6562.28808594, 7.48005986578e-15],
        [6563.12158203, 7.49293900174e-15],
        [6563.95458984, 4.59418727426e-15],
        [6564.78759766, 2.25848015792e-15],
        [6565.62109375, 1.04438093017e-15],
        [6566.45410156, 6.61019482779e-16],
        [6567.28759766, 4.45881319808e-16],
        [6568.12060547, 4.1486649376e-16],
        [6568.95361328, 3.69435405178e-16],
        [6569.78710938, 2.63747028003e-16],
        [6570.62011719, 2.58619514057e-16],
        [6571.453125, 2.28424298265e-16],
        [6572.28662109, 1.85772271843e-16],
        [6573.11962891, 1.90082094593e-16],
        [6573.953125, 1.80158097764e-16],
        [6574.78613281, 1.61992695352e-16],
        [6575.61914062, 1.44038495311e-16],
        [6576.45263672, 1.6536593789e-16],
        [6577.28564453, 1.48634721076e-16],
        [6578.11914062, 1.28145245545e-16],
        [6578.95214844, 1.30889102898e-16],
        [6579.78515625, 1.42521644591e-16],
        [6580.61865234, 1.6919170778e-16],
        [6581.45166016, 2.35394744146e-16],
        [6582.28515625, 2.75400454352e-16],
        [6583.11816406, 3.42150435774e-16],
        [6583.95117188, 3.06301301529e-16],
        [6584.78466797, 2.01059337187e-16],
        [6585.61767578, 1.36484708427e-16],
        [6586.45068359, 1.26422274651e-16],
        [6587.28417969, 9.79250952203e-17],
        [6588.1171875, 8.77299287344e-17],
        [6588.95068359, 6.6478752208e-17],
        [6589.78369141, 4.95864370066e-17]])


#Get the data
obs_wave, obs_flux = data[:,0], data[:,1]

#Center the x data in zero and normalized the y data to the area of the curve
n_wave = obs_wave - obs_wave[np.argmax(obs_flux)]
n_flux = obs_flux / sum(obs_flux) 

#Generate a distribution of points matcthing the curve
line_distribution   = np.random.choice(a = n_wave, size = 100000, p = n_flux)
number_points       = len(line_distribution)

#Run the fit
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 4)
gmm.fit(np.reshape(line_distribution, (number_points, 1)))
gauss_mixt = np.array([p * norm.pdf(n_wave, mu, sd) for mu, sd, p in zip(gmm.means_.flatten(), np.sqrt(gmm.covariances_.flatten()), gmm.weights_)])
gauss_mixt_t = np.sum(gauss_mixt, axis = 0)  

#Plot the data
fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 12))
axis.plot(n_wave, n_flux, label = 'Normalized observed flux')
axis.plot(n_wave, gauss_mixt_t, label = '4 components fit')

for i in range(len(gauss_mixt)):
    axis.plot(n_wave, gauss_mixt[i], label = 'Gaussian '+str(i))

axis.set_xlabel('normalized wavelength')
axis.set_ylabel('normalized flux')
axis.set_title('Sklearn fit GM fit')

axis.legend()
plt.show()
```

Which gives me:

[image]

And zooming

[image]

If anyone has attempted to use this library towards this purpose my questions are two:

1) Is there a class in sklearn to perform this fit without generating the data distribution as an intermediate step?

2) How should I improve the fit? Is there a method to constrain the variables? For example set all the narrow components with the same standard deviation?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: To my knowledge, there is unfortunately no way to avoid that intermediate step.
To improve the fit I would look into the class [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture) to see what you can do there. You can set initial wights for example, reduce the convergence threshold, etc..

Answer (score 2):

For question 1:

> Consequently, I generate a distribution from the numpy random.choice
>   function to generate a distribution weighted by the shape of my curve.
>   Afterwards I run sklearn fit:

That sounds correct to me. Another possible answer was given in [Fast arbitrary distribution random sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100716/fast-arbitrary-distribution-random-sampling)

For question 2:

When fitting models such as GMM, there is a technique called "variance flooring" to impede that components become very narrow (which could happen when one component (over)fits well just a few points). From [Schlapbach et al., A Writer Identification System for On-line
Whiteboard Data, 2001](http://www.dfki.uni-kl.de/~liwicki/pdf/SchLiBu07-01.pdf):

> [...] variance flooring is employed to avoid an overfitting of the
>   variance parameter. The idea of variance flooring is to impose a lower
>   bound on the variance parameters as a variance estimated from only few data
>   points can be very small and might not be representative of the underlying
>   distribution of the data. The minimal variance value is defined by

```
min_sigma**2 = phi * sigma_global**2
```

> where phi denotes the variance flooring factor and the global variance `sigma_global**2` is calculated on the complete training set. The minimal variance, `min_sigma**2`, is used to initialize the variance parameters of the model. During the EM update step, if a calculated variance parameter is smaller than `min_sigma**2`, then the variance parameter is set to this value.

That would however imply to modify the code. You might reach a similar effect by augmenting the `reg_covar` argument of `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture`.