# How to plot the pdf and cdf for an arbitrary function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, distribution, seaborn

I'm trying to make something like this:

[image]

A normalized histogram for a distribution with pdf or pmd plotted on it. The problem is that I could only use the distributions that are already in the python library for plotting this histogram. I want to have the same plot for my arbitrary discrete distribution that I defined. I was trying to use np.random.choice to make a sample array but the problem is that it is only useful if the array is small, otherwise, if we have a huge population it wont be useful.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np 
data = np.random.choice([10, 25, 34, 26, 44], size = 500, p = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0]) 
sns.distplot(data, norm_hist=True)
```

How could I define a function instead of writing an array and get random sample from that arbitrary function and then I could plot the sample as the way above?
something like this:

random_sampling(lambda x: some function)
and the output could be a sample that could be plotted using sns.distplot?

Comment: Give one or more examples of the function.

Comment: why not to plot the function directly without sampling?

Comment: Simple functions like: (exp(2*x)), (x**2), (2*x + 400),... that could be defined using lambda.

Comment: I am looking for defining a function for the distribution that the samples are selected. I think I was vague explaining it above, the main population is a huge data set, and for sampling from that data set, I am trying to have an arbitrary function instead of having a distribution that is already in the python library.

Comment: @N.Sh then is it correct to say you're looking for a way to obtain empirical pdf/cdf from a sufficiently large sample?

Comment: To be honest I am not really sure if that is the same. does the distribution function that the sampling is using impact the resulted pdf?

Comment: Do you mean inverse transform sampling? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100716/fast-arbitrary-distribution-random-sampling

Comment: I have seen topics that were on that matter but unfortunately it wasn't doing the function that I expected, I am hoping that I could have somehow a customized sampling of a huge data set and then plot the pdf of it, if that makes any sense?

Comment: When you say "I am trying to have an arbitrary function instead of having a distribution that is already in the python library.", what do you mean by "distribution that is already in the python library"?