# How do you draw a sample from a Seaborn distplot distribution?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have made a density distribution with the following code:

```
sns.distplot(df['Amount'], hist=True, kde=True,
             color = 'darkblue', 
             hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'},
             kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
```

How can I draw a random sample from this distribution?

Comment: Thank you @Emma. I did look through that document. The problem is that it only seems to discuss how to plot the distribution, not how to draw a sample from it

Comment: Since seaborn is a ***plot***ting library, it is probably expected that it can only ***plot*** distributions and cannot draw random samples.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, you're probably right. That's what I am concerned about. I think I'll try to find an alternative method to draw samples from then.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100716/fast-arbitrary-distribution-random-sampling) is a good start.