# Is there a python function similar to np.random.multivariate_normal that generates NON-NORMAL distribution?

Tags: python, simulation

Python function np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, n) generates NORMAL random series with given covariance  and mean. 
I would like to generate random series with given covariance and mean, but NOT NORMAL. 
Is there  such a funcion IN PYTHON?

In my case I have time series for 10 stock returns. Those returns are not normal-distributed.
I want to simulate 5000 returns for each stock, in such a way that  they have same mean and covariance as my original stocks returns.
I don't want those simulated returns to be normal-distributed, but rather to have a distribution  similar to the original stocks.

Comment: You're going to have to narrow this down a mite, since there are an infinite number of distributions that are not normal.

Comment: Excuse my bluntness here, but this is about as silly as saying "I want to know how to do care and feeding of an animal that isn't a squirrel."  How do you expect anybody to give you a meaningful answer to such an open-ended question?  The concept of care and feeding may be very clear, but the specifics can vary to extremes depending on what this unspecified animal actually is.

Comment: I forgive your blutness. But the question is correct. I want to tackle an unknown distribution. I think the answer lays in GMM.

Comment: Please skim the index of Luc Devroye's textbook on [Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf).  It's nearly 800 pages of very dense material, because the correct way to generate RVs depends entirely on the distribution.  Going back to the critter analogy, neither a shark nor a gerbil is a squirrel, but proper care and feeding of a shark is entirely different from that for a gerbil.  Since the only information you've provided is that your distribution is not normal, there's no way anybody here can provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can reach a random distribution you'd like by mapping a uniform distribution to an inverse CDF function (edit: if it has a closed form CDF, like @pjs mention below) of your distribution.

here is a good SO [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100998/3700626).
and here is a [good explanation](https://matlabtricks.com/post-44/generate-random-numbers-with-a-given-distribution) how to do it

Comment: No, you can't.  Not all distributions have closed form CDFs.  That's why there are a variety of non-inverse methods for generating RVs, such as convolution, composition, acceptance/rejection, and a whole bunch of special-case tricks.  See [Devroye](http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf) for lots and lots of details.

Comment: fixed - removed the "any" word

Comment: It's still not a true statement unless you know what specific distribution Rick wants, and know that it has a closed form CDF which is an invertible function.

Comment: the distribution doesnt have any specific form. It is a distribution of stock returns, which can be anything.